# Code doesn't run "Process exited with code: 0" AWS- CLOUD9 Using S3's

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-cloud9

Whenever I run my code, the menu doesn't launch at all and the result just says `"Process exited with code: 0"`. It's acting like the code is successfully running, but it's clearly not.

This is in a AWS-Cloud9 environment and using S3's. I am new to Python/coding and I'm not sure if I'm missing statements or what. Any help here would be very much appreciated.

*** Code below ***

```
import datetime
import logging
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def create_bucket():
    s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
    response = s3_client.create_bucket(Bucket="dylanreed123132")

    print(response)

def delete_bucket():
    s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
    response = s3_client.delete_bucket(Bucket="dylanreed123132")

    print(response)

def upload_object():
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3.meta.client.upload_file('C:/Users/Dylan/UMGC/SDEV400/S3 pics', 'dylanreed123132', 
'eagleslogo.png')

def delete_object():    
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    s3.delete.object(Bucket= 'dylanreed123132', Key='eagleslogo.png')

def copy_object():
    s3 = boto3.resouce('s3')
    copy_source = {
        'Bucket': 'projectfolder1',
        'Key': 'eagleslogo.png'
    }

    bucket = s3.Bucket('projectfolder2')

    bucket.copy(copy_source, 'eagleslogo.png')

    print('Single file is copied')

def download_file():
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3.Bucket('dylanreed123132').download_file('eagleslogo.png', 
'C:/Users/Dylan/eagleslogo.png')

def main():
    s3_handle = boto3.client('s3')
    while True:
        print("*** Welcome to the AWS S3 Functionality Console***")
        print("-Select one of the options below-")
        print("1. Create a new bucket")
        print("2. Put object in existing bucket")
        print("3. Delete object from existing bucket")
        print("4. Delete bucket")
        print("5. Copy an object from one bucket to another")
        print("6. Download an existing object from a bucket")
        print("7. Exit Program")
        selection=input("Enter option: ")

        if selection.upper() =="1":
            create_bucket()
        elif selection.upper() == "2":
            upload_object()
        elif selection.upper() == "3":
            delete_object()
        elif selection.upper() == "4":
            delete_bucket()
        elif selection.upper() == "5":
            copy_object()
        elif selection.upper() == "6":
            download_file()
        elif selection.upper() == "7":
            print("Goodbye!")
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            print ("Current date and time : ")
            print (now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show the output please. I'd imagine since you see no console "menu" that your issue is here: `s3_handle = boto3.client('s3')` which perhaps means your env doesn't have boto installed

Comment: @ViaTech I updated the post to show output. Also Boto3 is installed and was installed using "sudo python3 -m pip install boto3". Also if I remove that command line s3_handle = boto3.client('s3'), it still performs the same. Thank you in advance for your suggestions!